# Beginner: How do I upload an HTML only site to the web host?

Tags: html, hosting

I'm trying to make a simple four page website, all HTML with some CSS and images. This is my first site. After I'm done building the HTML documents, what do I need to upload them and get the site running?

Comment: you have to define in wich hosting you want to albergate your site :-D

Answer (score 0):

In order to put up a website, you need a web hosting provider. So the first thing you need is a hosting provider. Make sure that your provider offers FTP access to your website. You will need to contact your hosting provider (http://webdesign.about.com/od/webhosting/f/blfaqwebhosting.htm) if you aren't sure.

Once you have a hosting provider, in order to connect by FTP you need some specific information:

your username
password
the host name or URL where you should upload files
your URL or web address (especially if it's different from the host name
You can get this information from your hosting provider if you aren't sure what it is.

Make sure your computer is connected to the internet and that your WiFi is working.

Open an FTP client. As I mentioned above, most computers come with a built-in FTP client, but these tend to be fairly hard to use. It's better to use a visual style editor so you can drag and drop your files from your hard drive to your hosting provider.

Best FTP Clients for Windows
Best FTP Clients for Macintosh
Following the instructions for your client, put in your host name or the URL where you should upload your files.

If you try to connect to your hosting provider, you should be prompted for a username and password. Enter them in.

Switch to the correct directory on your hosting provider.

Select the file or files you want to load onto your website, and drag them to the hosting provider pane in your FTP client.

Visit the website to verify that your files uploaded correctly.

Tips:

Don't forget to transfer images and other multimedia files that are associated with your website, and put them in the correct directories.

It can often be easiest to just select the entire folder and upload all the files and directories at once. Especially if you have fewer than 100 files.

What You Need

FTP client

check this out http://webdesign.about.com/cs/beginninghtml/ht/htupload.htm i hope this could help you